# SQL Server 2008 R2: Calculated Member is SSAS not pulling correctly in SSRS

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssas

I have a calculated member in SSAS cube which gives a percentage. In the cube browser this aggregates correctly but in BIDS SSRS it adds all the grains together to give a meaningless result. I know I could average the results but this isn't acceptable as I need a weighted average, which is why I created the calculated member in the first place.  Help! How do I get this to work?

Here's the detail:

The calculated member in SSAS looks like this:

```
ActiveTimeVsExpectedActiveTime = (AvailableTime + TimeOnPhone + TimeInAvailable)/ExpectedTimeOnPhone
```

This works perfectly in the cube browser; it calculates correctly for all the individual telephone agents, and this feeds through the hierarchical group correctly to give a weighted result i.e. instead of adding together the result of the calculated member for each individual and calling that the team total, it sums together all the elements of the calculation and puts the results through the calculated member equation.

In SSRS however it just adds together the results of the individual calculated members and calls that the Team result. Help! I've searched online for a solution but can't find one. It doesn't make sense...why does the cube browser automatically calculate it correctly without any problem if SSRS doesn't - it makes calculated members rather pointless doesn't it?!

OK, so in response to Diego's question, I am including some of the data to clarify a bit further... The issue replicates on lots of calculated members; this is from the report I am building at the moment.  T

he calculated member is Adherence = Adhering Time / Rostered Time

This is what it looks like in SSRS reporting:

```
            Adhering Time   Rostered Time   Adherence                                               
    Team1       275736  366600  908.58%                                             
        Agent1  29355   30000   97.85%                                              
        Agent2  22041   33000   66.79%                                              
        Agent3  27493   30000   91.64%                                              
        Agent4  26689   30000   88.96%                                              
        Agent5  0   30000   0.00%                                               
        Agent6  27447   30000   91.49%                                              
        Agent7  30000   30000   100.00%                                             
        Agent8  28725   30000   95.75%                                              
        Agent9  0   32400   0.00%                                               
        Agent10 30142   31200   96.61%                                              
        Agent11 27201   30000   90.67%                                              
        Agent12 26643   30000   88.81%
```

As cou can see at the top of the data, it calculates the team adherence as being 908.58%, which is the sum of the adherence results of every agent.

SSAS cube browser shows exactly the same results for each agent but gives the team total as 75.21%, which it calcualtes as coming from 275736 adhering time and 366600 of rostered time.

Answer (score 0):

Calculated Memberes are calculated at run time. Any chance the data changed between the interval you compared the cube and the SSRS. Also, are you sure the hierarchy you are using to compare is the same. The [Product].Name can be different if you are browsing the product attribute of a DimProduct dimension for example and the product on a hierarchy containing other members

Comment: Thank you for the advice. The data has not changed since I ran the cube - I am looking at a single, completed day's data which we have completed the ETL for and we are not adding more data. I am definitely using the same hierarchy-it's pulling through from SSAS and we have very few hierarchies, which are clearly and very differently labelled.  I'm not sure what you mean about the product.name being different but I've checked all the individual parts of the calculations in both SSAS and SSRS and they are looking at the same data, the only difference is that the Cube Viewer calculates correctly

Comment: humm, maybe if you post some screens, it can help me understand the problem

Comment: Team1  275736 366600 908.58%
 Agent1 29355 30000 97.85%
 Agent2 22041 33000 66.79%
 Agent3 27493 30000 91.64%
 Agent4 26689 30000 88.96%
 Agent5 0 30000 0.00%
 Agent6 27447 30000 91.49%
 Agent7 30000 30000 100.00%
 Agent8 28725 30000 95.75%
 Agent9 0 32400 0.00%
 Agent10 30142 31200 96.61%
 Agent11 27201 30000 90.67%
 Agent12 26643 30000 88.81%